# Ext Js Slider or Multi Slider with Chart control

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

Is there any way we can have slider with chart(i.e bar chart or line chart)?. While changing the slider(assuming multi Slider with min and max) the graph has to be changed.

Assume a slider control is on below and charts is upper . Something relevant to my requirement i found in following Link.Can anyone suggest me how to achieve this is extjs 4 and below

For Example https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls

Comment: Yes you can. Slider has change event from which store backing chart can be filtered/changed. For more details you would have to create a chart and a slider in a sencha fiddle, try to get the change handler fired and then modify the store. If you have detail question, you can show us your code and we can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below snippet which I did considering your requirement and the example at https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        //default global data
        var data = [{ 'name': 'Michael',   'count': 5 },
                { 'name': 'Elisa',   'count':  7 },
                { 'name': 'Robert', 'count':  3 },
                { 'name': 'John',  'count':  2 },
                { 'name': 'Jessica',  'count': 6 },
                { 'name': 'Aaron',  'count': 1 },
                { 'name': 'Margareth',  'count': 8 }
        ];

        //custom function to filter data by new sliderVal
        var filterDataByCount = function(sliderVal) {
            var filteredData = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                //filter data whose count is less than sliderVal
                if(data[i].count < sliderVal) {
                    filteredData.push(data[i]);
                }
            }
            return filteredData;
        };

        //Define a store with fields name, count of cookies
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
            fields: ['name', 'count'],
            data: data
        });

        //Define a pie chart with above store
        var chart = Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
            width: 500,
            height: 350,
            animate: true,
            store: store, //store set to one that defined above
            theme: 'Base:gradients',
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                angleField: 'count',
                showInLegend: true,
                tips: {
                    trackMouse: true,
                    width: 140,
                    height: 28,
                    renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
                        this.setTitle(storeItem.get('name') + ' ate ' + storeItem.get('count') + ' cookies');
                    }
                },
                label: {
                    field: 'name',
                    display: 'rotate',
                    font: '18px Arial'
                }
            }]
        });

        //Define slider
        var slider = Ext.create('Ext.slider.Single', {
            width: 200,
            value: 50,
            increment: 1,
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 10,
            listeners: {
                changecomplete: function(slider, newVal) {
                    //reload chart with filteredData on slider change
                    chart.store.loadData(filterDataByCount(newVal));
                    //Ideally u should be loading filtered data by doing call to backend with queryparam set to "newVal"
                }
            }
        });

        //Define panel that is rendered on body and contains chart, slider items
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            layout: 'vbox',
            items: [
                chart,
                slider
            ]
        })
    }
});
```

You can refer to link for the same [Fiddle link](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1k56)